# Analog of `<<%~` not requiring Monoid for Traversal

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I need a function like [`<<%~`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-60--60--37--126-) which would act with `Traversal`s in similar fashion to [`^?`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-), like this:

```
(<<?%~) :: Traversal s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> (Maybe a, t)

> ix 0 <<?%~ succ $ [1,2]
(Just 1,[2,2])
> ix 1 <<?%~ succ $ [1,2]
(Just 2,[1,3])
> ix 2 <<?%~ succ $ [1,2]
(Nothing,[1,2])
```

How should I implement it? The obvious way is to apply `^?` and `%~` separately, but I'd like a solution in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we don't want to require a `Monoid` constraint on the targets, we have to specify ourselves the `Monoid` that will be used for combining the old elements in a traversal. As the goal is something analogous to `^?`, the appropriate monoid is `First`.

```
(<<?%~) :: LensLike ((,) (First a)) s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> (Maybe a, t)
l <<?%~ f = first getFirst . (l $ \a -> (First (Just a), f a))
```

Comment: I changed the framing around your solution rather drastically. Feel free to revert the changes if you don't like them.